# Por que uma function invocada por onclick não influencia em comandos externos a ela?

Tags: javascript, html, funções, onclick

Como pode ser visto no código, as variáveis declaradas são globais, e a rotina deveria exibir o resultado no console assim que o botão "Enviar" fosse selecionado.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="conta()">
<script>
  //VARIÁVEIS
  var numero = 5;
  var resultado;
  var pronto = false;
  //FUNÇÕES
  function conta(){
    resultado = numero + 5;
    pronto = true;
  }
  //ROTINA
  if (pronto == true){
  console.log(resultado);
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Mas ao ser executado, o console não é exibido. Se as variáveis forem declaradas de forma local dentro de `function conta()`, a operação é realizada (o que pode ser comprovado com um `console.log(resultado)` dentro da função. Mas isso não afeta o `console.log(resultado)` externo à ela.
O que devo fazer pra que essa função invocada por `onclick` interaja com as outras linhas do javascript?

Comment: O seu onclick executa a função `conta`, tudo que quiser fazer a partir do clique – incluindo logar resultados no console – tem de ser feito lá dentro. A parte que você chamou de rotina executa logo que a página carrega, e logo após a função conta ser criada, mas antes dela ser executada (ela só será executada no click).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez você esteja precisando aprender o que é [Programação Orientada a Eventos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_orientada_a_eventos). O Javascript é uma linguagem orientada a eventos (ao menos superficialmente) e esse paradigma controla o fluxo através de indicações externas, chamados [eventos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evento_(computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)).

Isso significa que ao criar uma função e atribuir a execução dela à um evento todo o trecho do código da função será executado a partir deste evento. Basicamente seu código está esperando uma ação do usuário para mudar o valor das variáveis, isso significa que o restante do seu código já foi executado independente do que há antes dele, ou seja, você está verificando o valor da variável antes dela ser mudada.

```js
var valor = false;

function clique() {
  
  valor = true;
  
  // o valor agora é 'true', pois a função foi executada só agora 
  console.log(valor);
  
}

// essa linha vai ser executada independente do que há antes dela. O valor ainda é 'false', pois o usuário ainda não clicou no link
console.log(valor);
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="clique()">Clique em mim!</a>
```

Geralmente as [funções](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funcionalidade) são [algoritmos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo) que são executados quando há uma chamada. Ao escrever sua função você não estará a executando. Para realizar a chamada em javascript você deve iniciar com o nome da função e finalizar inserindo os parâmetros entre parenteses `nomeFuncao('parametro1')`, caso não tenha nenhum parâmetro, os parenteses ficam vazios `nomeFuncao()`.

Quando você "linka" uma função à um evento de um DOM do HTML, por exemplo `onclick='nomeFuncao()'`, você está "dizendo ao javascript" que quando o usuário clicar neste DOM será executado os códigos da função `nomeFuncao` sem parâmetros.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, é o seguinte, este if só será chamado quando a página carregar; se quiser que ele fique sendo chamado sempre que clickar, o certo é por ele em uma função e chamar ela também:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="conta()">
<script>
  //VARIÁVEIS
  var numero = 5;
  var resultado;
  var pronto = false;
  //FUNÇÕES
  function conta(){
    resultado = numero + 5;
    pronto = true;
    rotina()
  }
  function rotina(){
    if (pronto == true){
      console.log(resultado);
    }
  }
  //ROTINA

</script>
</body>
</html>
```